# Spring-data-jpa + Hibernate not creating expected table

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Before you assume this is a duplicate, I'm aware of these answers (among others):

- [Hibernate not creating Table automatically in spring boot using postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411070/hibernate-not-creating-table-automatically-in-spring-boot-using-postgresql)
- [Unable to get Spring boot to automatically create database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema)
- [Spring Boot + Hibernate + Postgres - not creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053390/spring-boot-hibernate-postgres-not-creating-tables)

Still, auto-creating a table doesn't work!

I've used different versions of `Hibernate`, `Spring`, even implemented class `JpaConfig` from `JpaBaseConfiguration`, and adding deference properties from [common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

**Expected result:**

> Running hbm2ddl schema update

**Actual result:**

> Running hbm2ddl schema export

I see org.hibernate.cfj.Configuration `Iterator<Table> getTableMappings()` , but this method return emty list instead mapping class->table

Any help would be appreciated.

**Application.yml:**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/task-manager
    username: postgres
    password: password
    schema: public
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      naming-strategy: ru.ssau.common.naming_strategy.CustomNamingStrategy
      ddl-auto: create-drop

logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: DEBUG
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: TRACE
```

**Adding property driverClassName doesn't resolve it:**

**My entity:**

```
@Entity(name = "simple_user")
public class User extends PersistentObject {

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String nickname;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_id")
    private UserAccount userAccount;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public UserAccount getUserAccount() {
        return userAccount;
    }

    public void setUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount) {
        this.userAccount = userAccount;
    }
}
```

**Hibernate's output from console:**

```
HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your configuration following :

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
    properties:
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create-drop
```

Works well for me, using  1.4.3.RELEASE.

Comment: Yes, I've added this property, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: might be it is required to run this twice:  (you have had a database structure from your previous  run, which haven't been dropped, so during startup hibernate will try to create the database structure, but will fail, because tables already present; then you stop your application and drop cycle works.  within next startup the structure should be created)

Comment: nevertheless hibernate's    ddl-auto routines are bad practice, from my point of view.  I personally use this during my unit-tests.   and for production and integration testing I do use liquibase,   which I highly recommend to introduce in project.

Comment: I did this way 
1) Delete old database
2) Create new empty database with old name (task-manager)

Thank you for idea with liquibase. I'll try it later.

Answer (score -2):

I'm facing the same, but in my case just one of the various entitys is not automaticaly created on my database, let´s try to solve together.

My entitys seens like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tablename")
public class ClassName {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private long id;
    ...
```

Try to put the annotations like above and tell me if works.

Tks.

Comment: The question is not about auto generating Id, it's about table not being created